# Scraping a website that does not use td/tr tags for tables

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying a scrape a table in a website using Python, but the table in the website isn't in the tr td tags, so I don't know how to extract it. I tried extracting using the whole class but it just printed out stuff...Is there a way to extract these data?

[image: This is the source]

[image: This is the output i got]

So this is the code.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd

service = Service()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

website = 'http://stats.webclicktracer.com/?site_id=101254082&sitekey=37ca2c621f78b854'
driver.get(website)

all_matches_button = driver.find_element(
    By.XPATH, '//a[@title="Visitors"]')
all_matches_button.click()

table = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'grid-table')


for datas in table:
    print(datas.text)
```

Comment: At the bottom of the page there is an export button, download the table as a csv file.

Comment: Yes, but I want to scrape the data through Python code :(

Comment: So do it with the help of python - find the button, click on it, select the one you need from the list, save it on your computer. Always use the data prepared for you instead of reassembling the bike.

Comment: I still don't find the expected output as your screenshot navigating to the _Visitors_ page. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you, guys, for helping me out! I have been able to generate the data after looking through the website's API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in your first method you used 'find_elements()' with XPATH. And the second one I also put it like this for convenience. After looking at the HTML returned by the controller, I found the XPATH that you can use.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

service = Service()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

website = 'http://stats.webclicktracer.com/?site_id=101254082&sitekey=37ca2c621f78b854'
driver.get(website)

all_matches_button = driver.find_element(
    By.XPATH, '//a[@title="Visitors"]')
all_matches_button.click()

table = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/main/div[1]/div[2]/div/section/div/div/div[2]/div[1]")
print(table[1].text)
```

OUTPUT

```
4:43p
Streamtech Systems Technologies
/feature/2022/04/driving-the-iligan-bukidnon-road-via-rogongon/
4:41p
Telus
/top-stories/2023/06/ex-president-duterte-warns-implication-of-us-access-to-phl-military-bases/
4:41p
China Unicom
/
4:40p
Smart Communications
/2023/06/21/
4:40p
Royalcable Flash
/top-stories/2019/01/el-nino-forecast-drought-to-hit-9-provinces-in-mindanao/
4:40p
Philippine Long Distance Telephone
/business/2011/08/bfar-amenable-to-transition-period-on-close-fishing-season/
4:40p
Philippine Long Distance Telephone
/mindaviews/2017/12/state-of-the-municipality-address-build-malusos-future-today/
4:39p
Globe Telecom
/sports/2017/07/pinoy-aquaman-makes-splash-anew-in-cebu-bohol-swim/
4:39p
Globe Telecom
/top-stories/2022/12/ten-years-after-pablo-the-dead-are-still-awaiting-claimants/
4:39p
Tpg Internet
/category/top-stories/
4:38p
Globe Telecom
/top-stories/2019/07/davaos-daredevil-reveals-ugly-tnalak-motocross-experience/
4:38p
Globe Telecom
/top-stories/2023/06/70-year-old-woman-allegedly-kills-house-helper-in-davao-city/
4:38p
Globe Telecom
/mindaviews/2018/03/graduation-speech-not-afraid-failing-long-keep-learning-keep-winning/
4:37p
Ulsan Jung-ang Broadcasting Network
/peace-process/2015/06/japanese-foreign-minister-kishida-meets-gph-and-milf-officials-in-tokyo/
```